# Ansible docker_image unable to build docker image. CentOS 7

Tags: python, docker, ansible

Ansible **docker_image** module returns an error (scrolling to the end of ansible-playbook -vvvv output, the only meaningful thing)

```py
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 222
    f'Error while fetching server API version: {e}'
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Playbook** to install dependencies. I have tried adding different python versions as default for ansible tasks. Also, I've tried different docker versions and `docker` `docker-py` for pip install

```yaml
- name: Install required packages
  yum:
    name:
      - epel-release
      - ca-certificates
      - yum-utils
      - device-mapper-persistent-data
      - lvm2
      - git
      - docker-ce
      - docker-ce-cli
      - containerd.io
      - curl
    state: latest

- name: Install pip
  yum:
    name: python-pip

- name: Install Docker Module for Python
  pip:
    name: docker

- name: Start Docker service
  service:
    name: docker
    state: started
    enabled: yes
```

As well as different python versions with `vars` for each task

```
   vars:
     ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

**docker_image** task (I've tried community.docker.docker_image as well)

```yaml
- name: Build container image
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ image_name }}"
    source: build
    build:
      path: "{{ dockerfile_path }}"
    state: present
```

I am **able** to shh to host and build the image from Dockerfile by simply `docker build .`

So I managed to do it by running a shell script (but not by an actual commands with Ansible.builtin.shell)

```yaml
- name: Build container image
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  shell: sudo chmod +x builddocker.sh && ./builddocker.sh
  args:
    chdir: /opt/repo/Docker
```

**.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting shell script"
echo "building the docker image"
sudo docker build . -t docker_psql
```

*Back to the original question*: What am I doing wrong in Ansible with `docker_image` and installing dependencies (CentOS 7) ?

Comment: I think you have a Python version mismatch -- the error message references `python2.7`, but you really want `python3`. I'm not entirely sure how to convince CentOS to use `python3` as the default Python interpreter.

Comment: I get the same exception with `community.docker.docker_compose`. Switched back to `docker-compose` version `1.26.2`, because `1.27.0` dropped support for `Python 2.7`, but that didn't solve the problem.
Also get the same exception with `community.docker.docker_container_exec`.